# Expand UIView width when label inside has more text

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I have 2 UIViews with labels inside. The UIView should expand depending on the content in the label. Following is the layout:
[image]

Both of the above views can expand depending on the content in the label. I have tried to set layout with autolayout but the width is always fixed. Following are my constraints for second view:

[image]

First view constraints:
[image]

Comment: Not quite clear... in the image you posted, is `Quantity Val...` a `UIView` with light-gray background and rounded corners, and `0x` is a `UILabel` that is a subview of that gray view? If so, have you constrained that label's Leading and Trailing to the Leading and Trailing of the gray view?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your first view is missing a leading constraint to the label inside.

Comment: I just checked and it has all the constraints